# Comparing Week of Year with "overflow"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

So I want to be able to look at a specific week of the year and look at all data in the preceding and following 6 weeks.

WHERE t1.weeknum >= week-6 AND t1.weeknum <=week+6

So if week is 20, I want to return everything between 14 and 26.

The problem is weeks >=47 and <=6.  For instance, if week is 4, I want the range to be 50 through 10.  Years are a separate dimension and I am including all data regardless of year.

I think this would be similar to a compass heading.  Say you are at 350 degrees and turn right 30 degrees.  350+30 = 20 degree bearing.

I'm using SQL Server Express

Comment: Is this in a date table?

Comment: the week is stored as an int, but I can change that if needed

Comment: Can you please post some sample data? If you have a year field as well, that would be something to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Modulus operator (%)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) seems to be what you want. Since you are using the range `1` to `52` to represent week numbers you need to shift the range to `0` to `51` while calculating:

```
select WeekNumber,
  ( WeekNumber - 1 + 52 - 6 ) % 52 + 1 as WeekFrom,
  ( WeekNumber - 1 + 6 ) % 52 + 1 as WeekTo
  from ( values ( 1 ), ( 4 ), ( 6 ), ( 20 ), ( 50 ), ( 52 ) ) as Samples( WeekNumber );
```

By way of explanation:

- Start with `WeekNumber`.
- Subtract `1` to shift it to a zero-based range: `0` to `51`.
- For "from" values add `52` so that the result is always non-negative. This assumes that the input values are always in the range `1` to `52`.
- Add or subtract the desired offset (`6`).
- Use modulus to calculate the value with wraparound.
- Add `1` to shift the result back to a one-based range: `1` to `52`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the StartDate and EndDate in your WHERE clause. Please mark as answer if this is what you need.

```
declare @StartDayOfYear int
, @EndDayOfYear int
, @WeekNo int
, @YearNo int
, @WeekDate date
, @YearText varchar(4)
, @Start int
, @WeekOfStart date
, @WeekOfEnd date

set @WeekNo = 2
set @YearNo = year(getdate())
set @YearText = @YearNo
set @WeekDate = (select dateadd(day,1 - datepart(dw, @YearText + '-01-01') + (@WeekNo-1) * 7,@YearText + '-01-01'))
set @Start = (select datepart(dayofyear,@WeekDate))
set @StartDayOfYear = (select @Start - 42)
set @EndDayOfYear = (select @Start + 42)
set @WeekOfStart = (select Convert (date,dateadd (day, @StartDayOfYear, @WeekDate)))
set @WeekOfEnd = (select Convert (date,dateadd (day, @EndDayOfYear, @WeekDate)))

select @StartDayOfYear
, @EndDayOfYear
, @WeekDate as StartWeek
, CAST(DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @WeekOfStart), DATEDIFF(dd, -1, @WeekOfStart))) AS DATE) as StartDate
, CAST(DATEADD(wk, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 0-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @WeekOfEnd), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @WeekOfEnd))) AS DATE) as EndDate
```